# How to avoid CORS error when reading kml file from google maps

Tags: google-maps, cors, kml

I want to read kml file from url `https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1CUrmiiSysq2amCr5_6-YcOcg36sf3CpU&forcekml=1`

I can download it when I enter this url to the browser,
but I get CORS error when trying to read in php (server side) or js script (client side):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1CUrmiiSysq2amCr5_6-YcOcg36sf3CpU&forcekml=1' 
from origin 'https://my-app-domain.pl' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

scrip that I'm using

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // reading and parsing code will go here
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1CUrmiiSysq2amCr5_6-YcOcg36sf3CpU&forcekml=1", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I want to read this file automatically to extract and save some data in csv file.

I have tried to read kml file on server side (php script) using `file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1CUrmiiSysq2amCr5_6-YcOcg36sf3CpU&forcekml=1" )`
as [Professor Abronsius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603681/professor-abronsius) explained below, and it is working if access to the map is not restricted.

When I make map private I got error: `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden`

So on servers side access is forbidden and on client side there is CORS error.

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: What you can do, if you have PHP on your server(?), would be to create a proxy that downloads the file (curl) which you target with the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this particular endpoint does not need cURL to download - a simple `file_get_contents` is sufficient so the PHP proxy script can be very simple. If you use a session variable you need only send the request to Google a single time - subsequent requests can be served by the session variable.

For instance:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['task'] ) && $_POST['task']=='download-kml' ){
        if( !isset( $_SESSION['kml-file'] ) ){
            $_SESSION['kml-file']=file_get_contents( 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1CUrmiiSysq2amCr5_6-YcOcg36sf3CpU&forcekml=1' );
        }
        ob_clean();
        header('Content-Type: application/xml');
        exit( $_SESSION['kml-file'] );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps - KML cors issue bypass proxy</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            let fd=new FormData();
                fd.set('task','download-kml');

            fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd } )
                .then( r=>{ return r.text() })
                .then( data=>{
                    /* process the XML as you need */
                    console.info( data );
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks,
Actually what I need is one line
$data = file_get_contents( 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1CUrmiiSysq2amCr5_6-YcOcg36sf3CpU&forcekml=1' );

somehow now it is working :-) I need to understand why it was not before
probably access to map was restricted, and when I checked on client side i got another error (CORS) and that got me confused about the couse of the problem on server side

Comment: Solution is working if access to the map is not restricted.
When I make map private I got error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
So on server side access is forbidden and on client side there is CORS error.
Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: if you restrict access and need a username/password to access with a browser then you'd need to do the same with curl - possibly could do it by supplying a complex `context` argument to `file_get_contents`

Comment: The code above I tested almost exactly as written here and it worked absolutely fine. I was able to parse the XML response and query the DOM

Comment: Yes, it is working when access to map is not restricted (public access). You can Try now - when access to map is restricted. On client side authentication is made via google, when I'm logged with google account I have access to the map without asking for username/password

Comment: Well - rather than `file_get_contents` you might have to try using curl and log in before requesting the KML file/data. Using curl with extended debug info I get `The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden`